# Create a razor view dynamically for below database rows

Tags: asp.net-mvc

for BELOW table TechCourse contains courseName image and price I need to display these details dynamically using BELOW CShtml code. for each course, that above div code should display dynamically.

```
 +------------+-----------+---------------------+-------------+--+
|            |           |                     |             |  |
|  Course_ID | Name      | imageurl            | courseprize |  |
|     100    | Physics   | /images/physics.jpg | 750         |  |
|     101    | Maths     | /images/maths.jpg   | 800         |  |
|     102    | Biology   | /images/bio.jpg     | 800         |  |
|     103    | Chemistry | images/chem.jpg     | NULL        |  |
+------------+-----------+---------------------+-------------+--+
```

Div Code:

```
  <section class="popular-posts-block container">
        <header class="popular-posts-head">
            <h2 class="popular-head-heading">Most Popular Courses</h2>
        </header>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="slider popular-posts-slider">

                @foreach (var TechCourse in Model)
                {
                    <div>

                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <!-- popular post -->
                            <article class="popular-post">
                                <div class="aligncenter">
                                    <img src

     Here Course Image

     alt="image description">
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <strong class="bg-primary text-white font-lato text-uppercase price-tag">$99.00</strong>
                                </div>
                                <h3 class="post-heading"><a href="course-single.html">CourseName</a></h3>
                                <div class="post-author">
                                    <div class="alignleft rounded-circle no-shrink">
                                        <a href="instructor-single.html">
Here Image

<img src="http://placehold.it/35x35" class="rounded-circle" alt="image description"></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <h4 class="author-heading"><a href="instructor-single.html">Arfat</a></h4>
                                </div>
                                <footer class="post-foot gutter-reset">
                                    <ul class="list-unstyled post-statuses-list">
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">
                                                <span class="fas icn fa-users no-shrink"><span class="sr-only">users</span></span>
                                                <strong class="text fw-normal">98</strong>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">
                                                <span class="fas icn no-shrink fa-comments"><span class="sr-only">comments</span></span>
                                                <strong class="text fw-normal">10</strong>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <ul class="star-rating list-unstyled">
                                        <li><span class="fas fa-star"><span class="sr-only">star</span></span></li>
                                        <li><span class="fas fa-star"><span class="sr-only">star</span></span></li>
                                        <li><span class="fas fa-star"><span class="sr-only">star</span></span></li>
                                        <li><span class="fas fa-star"><span class="sr-only">star</span></span></li>
                                        <li><span class="fas fa-star"><span class="sr-only">star</span></span></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </footer>
                            </article>
                        </div>


                    </div>
                 }

            </div>


        </div>

    </section>
```

for the above table, TechCourse contains courseName image and price I need to display these details dynamically using above cshtml code. for each course, that above div code should display dynamically.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where exactly are you stuck? Where is your source code? Is there any connection to `c#` after all?

Comment: private List<DynamicCourses> LoadCourses()
        {
            List<DynamicCourses> myCourse = new List<DynamicCourses>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                DynamicCourses msvc = new DynamicCourses();
                msvc.CourseUrl = "course_url" + i.ToString() + ".html";
                msvc.CourseImageUrl = "image_url" + i.ToString() + ".jpg";
                msvc.Name = "Name " + i.ToString();
           
                myCourse.Add(msvc);}
            return myCourse;
        }

Comment: public ActionResult CourseService()
        {
          
            return View(LoadCourses());
        }

Comment: Please add everything relevant to your question, not to the comment section. Additionally, explain what **exactly** is not working as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the code below:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {

        var coursetab = (from list in dbcontext.Course_master orderby list.CreatedDate descending where list.Course_ID != 0 select list).ToList();


        return View(coursetab);
    }
```

ViewCode:

```
<section class="popular-posts-block container">
    <header class="popular-posts-head">
        <h2 class="popular-head-heading">Most Popular Courses</h2>
    </header>
    <div class="row">
        <!-- popular posts slider -->
        <div class="slider popular-posts-slider">



            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {

                <div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <!-- popular post -->
                        <article class="popular-post">
                            <div class="aligncenter">

                                <img src="~/Images/CourseImages/@item.Imageurl" style="height:147px;" />
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <strong class="bg-primary text-white font-lato text-uppercase price-tag"></strong>
                            </div>
                            <h3 class="post-heading"><a href="course-single.html">@item.Name</a></h3>
                            <div class="post-author">
                                <div class="alignleft no-shrink rounded-circle">
                                    <a href="instructor-single.html"><img src="http://placehold.it/35x35" class="rounded-circle" alt="image description"></a>
                                </div>
                                <h4 class="author-heading"><a href="instructor-single.html">Arfat</a></h4>
                            </div>

                        </article>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }

        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```